# Copying data from old table to new table in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm aware that copying data will only copy the data and no constraints, I'll lose my pk and fk etc.

But what if i were to copy the data back into a table with primary keys and foreign. because i want to remodel my db on workbench but don't want to lose the data i have imput into my tables so i was thinking of making a copy deleting the original remodelling the db and forward engineering and copying the data back into the table will this work?

Comment: Which is this, MySql or Oracle?

Comment: sorry I'm a noob at this well I create the database in Workbench then insert values in the command prompt i want to copy the tables in mysql on the command prompt...id that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I gut your question right but from what it looks you only need a new table with the data to mass with. have you tried using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * from old_t
```